# How do I add typings for an existing Angular1 $filter function in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

My filter (JavaScript):

```
angular.module('foo').filter('bar', function() {
  return function(a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c
  }
})
```

My consumer (TypeScript):

```
$filter('bar')('a', 'b', 'c') // Error: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature
```

[Here is the typing for $filter](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/cc3d223a946f661eff871787edeb0fcb8f0db156/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L676)

How can I add typings for my filter? I've tried the following, which doesn't seem to work:

```
interface BarFilter {
  (a: string, b: string, c: string): string
}

module angular {
  interface IFilterService {
    (name: 'bar'): BarFilter // Error: Specialized overload signature is not assignable to any non-specialized signature
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @basarat mentioned, you can specify this on every invocation on $filter to determine the type you expect to get back, e.g. as a specific version like this:

`$filter<BarFilter>("bar")("x", "y", "z")`

... which is not much better than using a type cast.

Another option is to extend the ng.IFilterService interface and add all the filters you registered there. Then when injecting the `$filter`, just specify `YourIFilterService` insted of `ng.IFilterService`:

```
interface YourIFilterService extends ng.IFilterService {
    (name: "bar"): BarFilter
}
```

And using it like this:

```
class BarController {
    constructor(private $filter: YourIFilterService) {}

    doBarFiltering() {
        var bars = this.$filter("bar")("x", "y", "z")
    }
}
```

In my opinion, this is a good way to achieve a pretty good level of type safety with not that much more effort, as you would add typings to `$filter` anyways (as `ng.IFilterService`).

Comment: that makes sense, thanks! but neither of these solutions is great. instead of parametrizing the type at every usage site, it would be nice to do once. and instead of extending the interface, it would be nice to just add a method to the existing `IFilterService` interface.

Comment: Yes, this should be a bit more elegant. But I think the second version is okay, because if you want to have the type safety on `$filter`, you already need to add the typings of `ng.IFilterService` in every controller or service constructor where you inject `$filter`, so in my opinion, it's not that much more work (as long as you always know what filters are added overall in your app.

Comment: do you think you can explain *why* i can't simply extend the `angular.IFilterService` interface? it seems that with the way interface merging works in typescript, this should work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to the provide the type explicitly (notice that `T` isn't determined by any of the inputs to the declaration of `$filter`). A quick one:

```
$filter<Function>('bar')('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: That does fix the 1st error (the 1st code block above), but I'm still unable to add typings for the existing filter (the 2nd code block). Also, why is it necessary to parameterize `$filter` with `Function`? Doesn't filter *always* take a `Function`?